# Sitio web deja de resolver request

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, iis

Tengo un sitio web desarrollado en asp.net c# con MVC y esta publicado en un servidor windows server 2012 r2.

El problema es que de manera aleatoria el sitio deja de resolver peticiones por ejemplo pulso un boton y no hay ninguna respuesta es como si no hiciera nada. luego de un par de minutos el sitio vuelve a funcionar con normalidad, pulso el mismo boton y ya hay respuesta.

Cuando analizo el trafico de red con las herramientas de chrome me aparece que las llamadas estan en pending.

Comment: Buenas, podrias hacer las mismas pruebas en otro navegador, como firefox ?

Comment: hemos realizado pruebas con IE, firefox y chrome.